# How to use MFA without relying on a smartphone?

Tags: multi-factor

We have a situation where our company's operators need to authenticate with a 6-character OTP on some websites.

For security reasons, we don't want them to use an app (eg.: Authy) on their personal smartphone or install OTP generator software on Windows.

Is there any other type of hardware that generates this type of code that doesn't need to be installed on Windows or smartphones?

Comment: This looks more like asking for product recommendations for me - which is off-topic. But a simple search for [otp token hardware](https://www.google.com/search?q=otp+token+hardware) will show you various existing products.

Comment: The search suggested by @SteffenUllrich gives very relevant results.

Comment: I gave it an answer under the assumption the person asking somehow missed the hardware token era.

Comment: A search using the relevant keywords in your question resulted in many hits. Please make sure you do some research before posting here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks research effort.

Answer (score 1):

They made and still make dedicated hardware OTP tokens.  I had one for my bank for years and even used one in my corporate environment well into 2010s.

For example as of 2023 in no order and not an endorsement of any:

- Symantec VIP Hardware Authenticator
- Thales SafeNet OTP 110
- HID ActivID